# How to define a column format for entire org-mode file

Tags: header-files, org-mode

PROBLEM:

For some reason when I copy and paste a column property format header in a org-mode file, such as

```
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM(Task) %5TODO(To-do) %1PRIORITY %10TAGS
```

to change the global properties of the trees of the file, it doesn't changes the default format. i.e. first column remains named as ITEM and not task (for this example). I've tried other changes and they are never applied.

TESTS:

- I have reloaded the column mode without success.
- Tried to add/delete columns with M-S-right/left and it updates the header/columns. But obviously I don't want to have to do it manually.

Here is my .emacs setup for org mode

```
;; Open ODT files with libre office
(defun my-org-export-to-odt-and-open ()
  (interactive)
  (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt)))

(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-support-shift-select 't)
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

Comment: Does it work after you close the file and reopen it? Does it work if you do `C-c C-c` on the `#+COLUMNS: ...` line after you paste it in?

Comment: Reopening the file didn't work. But the C-c C-c combo did! Thanks alot. I didn't saw any tutorial where they mentioned this. Thanks @Nick

Comment: Both of them should work: see [In-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness: when in-buffer settings like `#+COLUMNS: ...` are changed, the change does not take effect until you press `C-c C-c` on any in-buffer setting (although doing it on the just-changed setting is probably the most natural).

Alternatively, if you save and kill the buffer and visit the file anew, or
if you save the buffer and revert the buffer from the file, the change should take effect (the OP's lack of success with this notwithstanding - I'm not sure why it did not work).

The relevant documentation is [In-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings).